# Check mat-checkbox Checked unchecked using TypeScript in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am developing a solution with web api net core, angular 16, typescript, Material UIO and I need to check a checkbox depending of a value, that is, if the value is true, I check the checkbox, if not, I uncheck it.

I tried it with JavaScript using: `document.getElementById("remember").checked=` `true` or `false` depending on the case but it sends me an error.

The code that does not send me an error but does not check the checkbox, in typescript is:

```
this.formLogin.controls["remember"].setValue(true);
```

or false depending on the case.

The HTML code of the mat-checkbox is:

```html
<div class="row" style="margin-top: 0px !important; padding-top: 0px;">
    <mat-checkbox id="remember" value="checked" 
        style="text-align: left !important; vertical-align: top !important; margin-top: 0px !important; padding-left: 32px; padding-top : 0px !important;" 
        (change)="onChangeStatus($event)">Remember Me</mat-checkbox>
</div>
```

I have searched for solutions on Google and have not found any, that is why I turn to you for help

Comment: it looks like you didn't link your mat-checkbox to your formcontrol.  try adding `formControlName="remember"` to the `<mat-checkbox>`